# Need to understand how `yield` works for `pytest`?

Tags: python, pytest

I am using `pytest` to test python application(3.7) but I found it doesn't run a method with `yield` at the end.

Below is my python method:

```
def load(conn):
   print('Hello world')
   if conn.connected:
       yield True
```

Below is the test case:

```
def test_load():
    load(None)
```

when run the test case with `pytest`, the method `load()` is not event called. The test results show `pass`. How can I understand how `yeild` work with `pytest`?

Comment: This is more of an "understanding what `yield` means" issue than a pytest issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) turns a function into a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-generator) so calling `load()` returns a generator object without actually executing its content.

You could see what it returns if you run pytest with `-s` flag which prevents it from [capturing](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html#default-stdout-stderr-stdin-capturing-behaviour) the `print` output (`pytest -s [file]`):

```py
def test_load():
    print(load(None))
```

To actually execute the generator, you can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#next) to retrieve the next item produced by the generator:

```py
def test_load():
    next(load(None))
```